# How to skip remaining rules when a specific grule get executed and move to next iteration

Tags: go, rule-engine

golang Grule
just like continue statement in the for loop, I want to skip the remaining rules and start the next cycle.

https://github.com/hyperjumptech/grule-rule-engine

tried using retract but it removes rule for next iteration and not current iteration.

faq or tutorials do not have any information of the same

Answer (score 2):

Try adding Complete() to the end of the THEN statements of rules if want it to stop rule evaluation.